# Issues with parsed data available in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok, filebeat, kibana-7

Below issues are coming up while we are testing nginx parsing script

1. Parsing the script via  input source as file seems to work fine.  we are able to see all the fields being parsed  and getting the desired output in stdout.
2. While testing the script by setting beats input and output sent to ES, (created a new index ‘valtest’, ) at the time of index creation able to view that there are 40 fields.  But at the time of viewing the data via discover, could see only 9 fields available available.

Can anyone suggest how to troubleshoot why all the fields are not listed in the new index in logstash.

Comment: I ever had this similiar problem before and it was because ``Hide missing field`` was ticked. try to untick this

Comment: And I personally with check the mappings by :
options > stack management > index management > search your index > mappings,
are the fields you looking for there?

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This worked.  Once I unchecked the Hide Missing field option, I was able to see all the fields.

Comment: Good to know! cheers

Comment: Actually I was able to get the fields listed. But the data associated with the fields is not coming up.  Anything else I need to check ?

Comment: are you using time fields? have you try to pull the time fields from the far beginning? I will manually search for the file first to assure the data is in or not, if you can find the message then probably there is a parsing problem.

Comment: also, you maybe want to share your ``filebeat.yml`` and a sample of your data

Comment: I have checked the file.  The data is in there.  Im trying to parse the access logs (nginx server logs) .I was able to display the fields by unchecking the hide missing fields option.  But the associated data is not coming up in Discover field data column

Comment: can you copy the data from the file, then search it in discover on message fields?
again, are you using time fields and have you pull it until the range of your data time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234627/discussion-between-vr3w3c9-and-yuliansen).

Comment: Sorry, it would be easier for you to add you filebeat.yml so other masters can help you with your problem.